# Easypost.com integration laravel - send forms

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite a beginner in Laravel. I understood CRUD, OOP, created some small apps.
But now I need to integrate easypost.com API to Laravel project.
I wanna create a simple postage calculator for now.
I have a page where are forms on the bottom and below forms, I wanna show all postage options with rates, etc.
Now I have PostageCalculator controller and putting to index function this:

```
public function index()
{
   
    \EasyPost\EasyPost::setApiKey(env('EASYPOST_API'));

    $shipment = \EasyPost\Shipment::create(array(
        "to_address" => array(
          'name' => 'Dr. Steve Brule',
          'street1' => '3993 Glen Meadow Dr',
          'city' => 'Norcross',
          'state' => 'GA',
          'zip' => '30092',
          'country' => 'US',
          'phone' => '3331114444',
          'email' => 'dr_steve_brule@gmail.com'
        ),
        "from_address" => array(
          'name' => 'EasyPost',
          'street1' => '417 Montgomery Street',
          'street2' => '5th Floor',
          'city' => 'Brno',
          'state' => 'CZ',
          'zip' => '60200',
          'country' => 'CZ',
          'phone' => '3331114444',
          'email' => 'support@easypost.com'
        ),
        "parcel" => array(
          "length" => 1,
          "width" => 1,
          "height" => 1,
          "weight" => 352.74
        )
      ));

      
    return view ('pages.rates', [
        'shipment' => $shipment
        
     ]);
        
  
}
```

So I send $shipment variable to rates.blade.php view and use foreach to show all info I need.
But also I have a form, where I want to select for example shipping and delivery country and can allow users to type their weight, dimensions, etc, so I created this form

```
     <form action="/rates" method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('post')
        
    {{-- Zeme odeslani --}}
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Země odeslání</label>
        @error('text')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{$message}}
          </div>
        @enderror
      <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected>Vyberte zemi</option>
        <option value="CZ" name="CZ">Česká republika</option>
        <option value="US" name="US">USA</option>
        <option value="SK" name="SK">Slovensko</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Země doručení</label>
    @error('text')
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{$message}}
      </div>
    @enderror
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected>Vyberte zemi</option>
    <option value="CZ" name="CZ">Česká republika</option>
    <option value="US" name="US">USA</option>
    <option value="SK" name="SK">Slovensko</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Rozměry:</label>
        @error('text')
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{$message}}
          </div>
        @enderror
    <div class="row">
        
      <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight" placeholder="Váha (kg)" ></div>
      <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="width" placeholder="Šířka (cm)" ></div>
      <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="height" placeholder="Výška (cm)" ></div>
      <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="`lenght`" placeholder="Délka (cm)" ></div>
    </div>
<br>
      < button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Spočítat cenu</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

and button with type="submit".
My problem is I know that I need to somehow use the store () function at my controller to get the request from the form, however, I don't know how.

I wanted to take $shipment request from index() function, but I am using foreach at the blade and it doesn't know variable $shipment.
and also I have no idea how to works with 2 options forms.
if I have select

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected>Vyberte zemi</option>
        <option value="CZ" name="CZ">Česká republika</option>
        <option value="US" name="US">USA</option>
        <option value="SK" name="SK">Slovensko</option>
      </select>
```

one select form is for ship address from and the second one for the delivery address.
How to get requests from the form and show the results from EasyPost on the same package calculator page?
tried something like:

```
'country' => $request->input['formname'],
```

but no luck.
Also, I have no idea how to create and separate values for a ship from and ship to select form.
Can you advise, please?
Thanks a lot., This is quite new for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish your need you have to think this process as an application lifecycle.

Basically; you want to show a form on a page, user needs to fill and post it, you will use inputs to prepare your address parameters and give them to Easypost api, when you got response from api, you will pass it to a view to show results on screen.

When I check your form blade, there isn't any `name` property on your select fields. You need something like this;

```
<select name="from_country" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected>Vyberte zemi</option>
    <option value="CZ" name="CZ">Česká republika</option>
    <option value="US" name="US">USA</option>
    <option value="SK" name="SK">Slovensko</option>
</select>
```

and other one;

```
<select name="to_country" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
    <option selected>Vyberte zemi</option>
    <option value="CZ" name="CZ">Česká republika</option>
    <option value="US" name="US">USA</option>
    <option value="SK" name="SK">Slovensko</option>
</select>
```

Now you can access this fields selected options from request;

```
public function show_result(Request $request)
{
    $from_country = $request->from_country;
    // OR
    $from_country = $request->input('from_country');
}
```

You can find other usage examples of `$request->input(...)` here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-an-input-value

So; you need to create 2 routes; 1 for show form and 1 for process form and show results.

In the `routes/web.php` file;

```
Route::get('form', [\App\Http\Controllers\PostageCalculator::class, 'form']); // to show form
Route::post('result', [\App\Http\Controllers\PostageCalculator::class, 'result']); // to show results
```

In the `app/Http/Controllers/PostageCalculator.php` file;

```
// define your methods in your Controller class
public function form()
{
    $data = []; // prepare any daha if you need anything on your form but as I see you don't need any
    return view('form', $data);
}

public function result(Request $request)
{
    // if you need any validation for form fields you can use $request->validate([...]);
    // you can access all posted input fields which specified with a name
    $to_address = array(
          'name' => $request->input('to_address_name'),
          'street1' => $request->input('to_address_street1'),
          'city' => $request->input('to_address_city'),
          'state' => $request->input('to_address_state'),
          'zip' => $request->input('to_address_zip'),
          'country' => $request->input('to_address_country'),
          'phone' => $request->input('to_address_phone'),
          'email' => $request->input('to_address_email')
        );
    $from_address = array(
          'name' => $request->('from_address_name'),
          'street1' => $request->('from_address_street1'),
          'city' => $request->('from_address_city'),
          'state' => $request->('from_address_state'),
          'zip' => $request->('from_address_zip'),
          'country' => $request->('from_address_country'),
          'phone' => $request->('from_address_phone'),
          'email' => $request->('from_address_email')
        );
    $parcel = array(
          "length" => $request->input('length'),
          "width" => $request->input('width'),
          "height" => $request->input('height'),
          "weight" => $request->input('weight'),
        );

    \EasyPost\EasyPost::setApiKey(env('EASYPOST_API')); // you should use config('services.easypost.api_key') instead of env(...)

    $shipment = \EasyPost\Shipment::create([$to_address, $from_address, $parcel]);

    return view('result', compact('shipment'));
}
```

To access input data with `$request->input('name')` you need give all fields their own unique name.

In `resources/views/form.blade.php`

```
<form action="{{ url('result') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    From address:<br>
    <input name="from_address_name" placeholder="from_address_name"><br>
    <input name="from_address_street1" placeholder="from_address_street1"><br>
    <input name="from_address_city" placeholder="from_address_city"><br>
    <input name="from_address_state" placeholder="from_address_state"><br>
    <input name="from_address_zip" placeholder="from_address_zip"><br>
    <select name="from_address_country" class="form-select">
        <option selected>Select Country</option>
        <option value="CZ" name="CZ">Česká republika</option>
        <option value="US" name="US">USA</option>
        <option value="SK" name="SK">Slovensko</option>
    </select><br>
    <input name="from_address_phone" placeholder="from_address_phone"><br>
    <input name="from_address_email" placeholder="from_address_email">
    <hr>
    To address:
    From address:<br>
    <input name="to_address_name" placeholder="to_address_name"><br>
    <input name="to_address_street1" placeholder="to_address_street1"><br>
    <input name="to_address_city" placeholder="to_address_city"><br>
    <input name="to_address_state" placeholder="to_address_state"><br>
    <input name="to_address_zip" placeholder="to_address_zip"><br>
    <select name="to_address_country" class="form-select">
        <option selected>Select Country</option>
        <option value="CZ" name="CZ">Česká republika</option>
        <option value="US" name="US">USA</option>
        <option value="SK" name="SK">Slovensko</option>
    </select><br>
    <input name="to_address_phone" placeholder="to_address_phone"><br>
    <input name="to_address_email" placeholder="to_address_email">
    <hr>
    Parcel:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="weight" placeholder="Váha (kg)" ><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="width" placeholder="Šířka (cm)" ><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="height" placeholder="Výška (cm)" ><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="`lenght`" placeholder="Délka (cm)" ><br>
    <button type="submit">Show Results</button>
</form>
```

(I didn't use any class/styles here but every input field have a name)

Now your `/form` route works and shows a form. And you post it to `/result` route to catch input fields and calculate `$shipment` result. You need to show `$shipment` data on your `resources/views/result.blade.php` file.

In `resources/views/result.blade.php` file;

```
<h1>Calculation Result</h1>
@foreach($shipment->rates as $rate)
    {{ $rate->service }} <br>
    {{ $rate->carrier }} <br>
    {{ $rate->rate }}
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

Actually I didn't use easypost api before but I checked documentation: https://www.easypost.com/docs/api/php#shipments-create-codesample

I think that's all and you need to check and edit code samples from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh finally I understood this! I ll try it later again and will let you know
Thank you sooo much

Answer (score 0):

I did session::put on the request and used this session for to pass data to the index(). This solution works, if you ll have something better, let me know thanks a looot